# What is the difference between Platform CDN and Cloudflare?

Tags: caching

The cloud provider I use(Acquia) has a set of API endpoints, and one of them is to clear caches, including Platform CDN + Varnish.

When I read Platform CDN, it gets me wonder where Cloudflare then sits as the CDN provider?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the big Drupal hosts now offer some kind of CDN:

- Acquia has Platform CDN (not sure what this is underneath)
- Pantheon has what they call a "Global CDN" but it is also rebranded Fastly
- PlatformSH offers Fastly on dedicated plans

The configuration for these CDNs is managed by the web host, so the layers are:

1. Your registar (for example.com), where you set nameservers to point to the host
2. Webhost's CDN
3. Webhost's webservers

Now, some people really like CloudFlare or they want to use a CloudFlare-only feature, like their Analytics or Page Rules or something.  (We'll use CloudFlare as an example here, but it could be another CDN, too.  There's nothing that makes this question CloudFlare-specific.)

In that case, you may add a separate CDN on top of the webhost's CDN, which would give you layers like this:

1. Your registrar, where you point the nameservers to CloudFlare
2. Cloudflare's CDN, which points to your webhost
3. Webhost's CDN
4. Webhost's webservers

This is generally overkill and makes things more complicated because now if you need to clear all caches, you need to clear CloudFlare plus the host's CDN cache plus your Drupal cache.  In addition, you probably won't get much support from the host for this second CDN, so you'll likely need to write some custom code to make sure your site and the second CDN are working together properly.

But if you want to do it, it's possible.